# React unit test for Context and Reducer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I have created a `LauoutContext.js` for my application needs. Also used  `router` location to get the URL / pathname. And passing reducer to child.

**JS File: LayoutContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Dashboard from '../components/layouts/primary/Dashboard'
import layoutReducer from '../reducers/layoutReducer'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const LayoutContext = createContext()
const LayoutContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [leftDrawerSelectedItem, layoutDispatch] = useReducer(
  layoutReducer,
  useLocation().pathname
)
return (
  <LayoutContext.Provider value={{ leftDrawerSelectedItem, layoutDispatch }}>
    <Dashboard>{props.children}</Dashboard>
  </LayoutContext.Provider>
  )
}

LayoutContextProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object
}

export default LayoutContextProvider
```

****Test File:** LayoutContext.test.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

import LayoutContext from '../LayoutContext'
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard'
import LayoutContextProvider from '../LayoutContext'

test('LayoutContext test', () => {
  const tree = (
    <LayoutContext.Provider value={null}>
      <Dashboard />
    </LayoutContext.Provider>
 )

 const { getByText } = render(tree)

 expect(getByText('Something')).toBeInTheDocument()
 })
```

**Error:**

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

*How can I test this Context?*

**Here Dashboard.js file:**

```
const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const { children } = props
  const classes = useStyles()
  let location = useLocation()


 return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <main className={classes.main}>{children}</main>
    </div>
  )
 }

Dashboard.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.node
}
export default Dashboard
```

Comment: can you show dashboard code?

Comment: @adel : I added dashboard code

Comment: `useLocation` is for react-router-dom you need to mock it or wrapping the component with `BrowserRouter` in the test.

Comment: @adel would you please provide me a resource ?

Comment: check my answer !

Answer (score 0):

here how to mock the`useHistory` of `react-router-dom`:

```
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useLocation: () => ({
    pathname: "/",
  }),
}))
```

or you need to wrap your component with BrowserRouter :

```
<LayoutContext.Provider value={null}>
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Dashboard />
 </BrowserRouter>
</LayoutContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.  

--> its for line# <LayoutContext.Provider value={null}>